# Linux shell: What does -f do?

Tags: linux, sh

I have a linux .sh file with something like:

```
scripts_dir='/opt/myapp/scripts'
[ -f "${scripts_dir}/common.sh" ] && . "${scripts_dir}/common.sh"
```

scripts_dir defines a variable to represent a directory.

What are we then trying to do in next line?

Comment: Try: `help test`

Comment: `[` is basically an alias for `test`, so you can use `man test`. Your shell might have a builtin version of `test` to speed things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if child script file exists, run the child script and will update current shell environment of the running script.

[Run a shell file in the current environment](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=descriptions-dot-run-shell-file-in-current-environment)